# How to create a pdf from tiff image using PDFBox for Android?

Tags: android, pdfbox

I have an android application that creates a pdf from images using PDFBox, but it does not work when the image is in tiff format.Is it not possible to create a pdf from tiff image using PDFBox?

Comment: Please press the green checkmark / upvote if the answer by MatPag is good for you. If it isn't, please comment below the answer to explain what troubles you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PDImageXObject.createFromFile(...)](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromFileByContent(java.io.File,%20org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument)) to let the library decide which is the best option to convert your image in a `PDImageXObject`, starting with the 2.X.X release of PDFBox.

You can read [here](http://www.paulzepernick.com/java/java-apache-pdfbox-convert-multipage-tiff-to-pdf/) to get some help on this, there is a code sample which you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: There's a convenience method `PDImageXObject.createFromFile()` which I've seen in the source code of PDFBox for android, it will do the job for you to choose the correct factory. Don't know if it is in their current release.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i've updated my answer with your information ;)